# I want to change the image path setting to an absolute path(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, src

Here is my JSON Code

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "ge" : "{require('../images/ppk1.jpg')}",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "ge" : "{require('../images/ppk2.jpg')}",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "ge" : "{require('../images/ppk3.jpg')}",  
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "ge" : "{require('../images/mypage_1.jpg')}",
  }
]
```

Here is my React Code

```
import React from 'react';
import Location from '../assets/Location.json';
class Contents extends React.Component {
render() {

const List = Location.map(v => (
 <li key = {v.id}>
    <div className="col-xs-12 location-bar__image">
      <a href="">
        <img src={v.ge} className="img-responsive curving" style={{border: "1px solid #bbb"}} alt="" />
      </a>
       <p className="location-bar__text__text">{v.text}</p>
    </div>
   )
)

return(
    <div>
      {List}
    </div>

   );
 };
}
```

Here is error code

[image]

I want to set the path except for localhost

Or is there another way to route images?

Comment: Are you able to alter the way the JSON is created?

Comment: sure !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you make each JSON entry like this, you'll probably be much closer`{
    "id": "1",
    "ge" : "images/ppk1.jpg"
  },`